# is it possible en MVVM use Auto in a property and make binding to the view model?

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-4.0

I have a control in the view, and its Height property is set as Auto. but I would like to have in the view model a propery that has the value in pixels of the Height property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try to bind to `FrameWorkElement.ActualHeight`. Pls, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I'm saying 'try', because I don't know whether it's bindable.